# How to update a ng-include value when I click someWhere else than a div with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've this very simplified html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-include="template"></div>
</div>
```

My template1.html only contains:

```
<div id="i1" ng-click="clickFunction()">Content of template1.html</div>
```

The template2.html:

```
    <div id="i2"> Content of template2.html </div>
```

And the following JS :

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.template = 'template1.html';

    $scope.clickFunction = function () {
        $scope.template = 'template2.html';
    }
}
```

When I click on my included template my second template is loaded in place of the first one.

What is the clean Angular method to replace back the template2 with the template 1 when I click everywhere else on my page (but not in my `ng-include` div)?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/MfHa6/251/)** a basic fiddle if it can help.

**Edit** :

I've tested to add the following code into my controller but the template view isn't updated (but the console.log yes, [very strange behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/MfHa6/255/)...):

```
jQuery('html').click(function() {
    console.log('Click on HTML')
    $scope.template = 'template1.html';
});

jQuery('#i2').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the model outside angular environment, you have to use apply() method of scope to update.

```
$scope.template = 'template1.html';
$scope.$apply();
```

Also I updated the fiddle such that it meets your requirement.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/292/)